# How to set user PATH permanently on Mac OS Catalina zsh shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, zsh, pipenv

How do I set user PATH permanently to be able to access Pipenv from the zsh shell on Mac Catalina?

I am installing Pipenv for the first time. After successful installation, I cannot access it from the zsh shell. However, when I ran this code (I found somewhere else):

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

I am able to run Pipenv from the terminal but only for that instance. Because, when I close and reopen the terminal, it doesn't work again until I run the code over again.

```
User@User-- ~ % pipenv
```

**Error**

```
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

Comment: Just do a `brew install pipenv`

Comment: See the section "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" in `man zsh` for an overview of the files `zsh` looks at on startup. The process is both broader and slightly different from how `bash` works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `bash`, you would have added `PATH="$PATH:$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"` to your `.bash_profile`, so that each `bash` session would have the proper directory to `PATH`.

In `zsh`, you would add that line to `.zprofile` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for a way to avoid installing pipenv globally as was recommended by the "pragmatic installation from the pip website": https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv and this solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
cd && touch .zprofile && open .zprofile
```

This command will create and open a `.zprofile` file, and every path you save in the file will be permanently available on the terminal.

Android SDK paths for examples:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

For macOS versions that are older than macOS Catalina use `.bash_profile` instead of `.zprofile`

Answer (score 3):

At macOS Catalina ver: 10.15.3, i modified the **~/.zshrc** file and worked for me for the default terminal (zsh).

I had created the ~/.bash_profile file and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Homebrew, then another option is to install `pipenv` like so:

`brew install pipenv`

This installs it globally. Since `pipenv` can manage even different python versions via [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), it's preferable to have it set up like this instead of installing it only for a specific python version using `pip`.

Comment: This works too, just that I didn't want to install it globally. I wanted to do a user installation to avoid breaking any system wide packages as I am new to programming. Ended up adding the PATH using .zprofile on zsh